# SQL Server : case when statement in query using LEFT(xxx,15)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a query I'm working on in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I'm not sure how to accomplish something.

Here's the current query:

```
SELECT DISTICNT 
    PRONOTES.CPK,
    REPLACE(PRONOTES.SUBJECT, ',','') AS SUBJECT,
    PRONOTES.CREATOR,
    PRONOTES.DATE_CREATED
FROM 
    PRONOTES
WHERE 
    DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
```

My issue is that the software creates a SUBJECT that includes a prescription number when an order is discontinued. So I get results in the SUBJECT column that look like this:

```
Discontinued RX #2341241341
Discontinued RX #23455859900
```

All other possible SUBJECTS are locked because users have to select them from a dropdown, it's just this instance that causes that unique value. I'm trying to measure productivity of different users by how many notes they create and what types of notes they create.

I'd like the results to just show "Discontinued RX" instead of including the number, so that when this gets shipped off to excel and a pivot table is created there won't be a million lines because of the uniqueness of that prescription number.

I can't do it with a simple:

```
LEFT(REPLACE(PRONOTES.SUBJECT, ',', ''), 15)
```

because then I'll lose too much data from other subjects, so I was wondering how to do this with a case when or if there's some other better way. I thought maybe modification so that only subjects that start with the words "Discontinued Rx" get chopped off.

Right now it generates this:

[image: current]

But I'd like this:

[image: desired]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression on `SUBJECT` so that when it starts with `Discontinued RX` that is all you show:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PRONOTES.CPK,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(PRONOTES.SUBJECT, 15) = 'Discontinued RX' THEN 'Discontinued RX'
         ELSE REPLACE(PRONOTES.SUBJECT, ',','')
    END AS SUBJECT,
    PRONOTES.CREATOR,
    PRONOTES.DATE_CREATED
FROM PRONOTES
WHERE DATE_CREATED BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simplistic pattern that you can then adjust into a CASE statement in your `SELECT` statement as required.

```
DECLARE @test varchar(100) = 'Discontinued RX #2341241341 Discontinued RX #23455859900'

SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('Discontinued RX #%', @test) > 0 THEN 'Replace' ELSE 'Keep' END
```